# Android Google MLKit face detection check if detected face bounding box is inside another view

Tags: android, face-detection, google-mlkit

I'm developing an Android application which capable of detection face

I need to check whether the detected face is inside a specific view (An instruction Circle for user to place their face on). I'm able to get the face bounding box but it seem to reference the `imageAnalysis` coordinate system. How to check if the detected face are inside a circle view? (from a root view coordinate system)

I'm using below `analyzer` for `imageAnalysis`:

```
override fun analyze(image: ImageProxy) {
   val mediaImage = imageProxy.image
   val inputImage = InputImage.fromMediaImage(mediaImage, imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)
   val listFaces = detector.process(image)

}
```

I'm able extract the `boundingBox` from detected `Face` from `listFaces`

Comment: You can check the ML Kit sample app to see how it transfers the result coordinate to the view coordinate.
https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/java/CameraXLivePreviewActivity.java

Comment: the sample seem quite complicated, is there a util that help us with the transformation? can we use: CoordinateTransform https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/camera/view/transform/CoordinateTransform